# How to Multiply 2 columns inside a sum function

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

In my products database i have a column for price and quantity. What i want to do is to multiply the price and quantity of each row and then add all the value so i can get the total price of all of my products in my database here is my code:

Products model:

```
public function getTotalAmountProducts()
{
   $this->db->select('sum(price*quantity) as stockvalue', FALSE);
    $query = $this->db->get('products');
   return $query->result();
}
```

Controller:

```
$this->data['totalamount'] = $this->products_model->getTotalAmountProducts();
```

it does not work. please help

Comment: Can you try, `$this->db->select('sum(\`price\`*\`quantity\`) as totalValue', FALSE);`

Comment: i get an output of 0.... some of my products have 0 quantity btw.

Comment: Can you provide your table structure?

Comment: Price = decimal(25,4)
quantity = decimal(25,4)

Comment: Can you edit your post and explain what do you want correctly? Which one do you want to calculate "total amount of all your products" or "total amount of single product type"?

Comment: in my products database i have a column for price and quantity.. what i want to do is to multiply the price and quantity of each row and then add all the value so i can get the total price of all of my products in my database.

Comment: i tried return $query->result(); but its does not work as well

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
public function getTotalAmountProducts()
{
  $this->db->select('price*quantity as stockvalue', FALSE);
  $query = $this->db->get('products');
  return $query->row()->stockvalue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function getTotalAmountProducts() {
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT sum(price* quantity) as stockvalue FROM products");
return $query->row()->stockvalue;
}
```